# iSCSI port virtualization techniques

Tags: iscsi

I need to create a scaled up iSCSI setup for some testing (around 1024), but all I have is limited hardware. My requirement is to create a large number of iscsi ports, which has unique IQN names and can be discovered at a storage controller as separate physical entities.

In FC, I should be able to do it with NPIV, where I could virtualize a single port to have multiple number of WWNs. But I don't find an equivalent solution in iSCSI.

Any suggestions?
I don't have any simulators like SANBLAZE handy. So I am trying to explore options which can be done at operating system level.

Answer (score 0):

You can use software iscsi to set up as many targets as you like (and have backing store for).

For example, you can use openSUSE (disclaimer: I work for SUSE) running something like Leap 42.2 and use targetcli to set up targets. The man page for targetcli(1) is pretty clear on examples. You can, for example, set up a separate 1Gig file for each target -- that is, if you have 1T of storage. Scale down the size so 1024 of them fit on your disc.